# Python noob can't get class method to work

Tags: python, class-method

I have a method in my `Customer` class called `save_from_row()`. It looks like this:

```
@classmethod
def save_from_row(row):
    c = Customer()
    c.name = row.value('customer', 'name')
    c.customer_number = row.value('customer', 'number')
    c.social_security_number = row.value('customer', 'social_security_number')
    c.phone = row.value('customer', 'phone')
    c.save()
    return c
```

When I try to run my script, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import.py", line 16, in <module>
    Customer.save_from_row(row)
TypeError: save_from_row() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I don't understand the mismatch in the number of arguments. What's going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first argument to a `classmethod` is the class itself.  Try

```
@classmethod
def save_from_row(cls, row):
    c = cls()
    # ...
    return c
```

or

```
@staticmethod
def save_from_row(row):
    c = Customer()
    # ...
    return c
```

The `classmethod` variant will enable to create subclasses of `Customer` with the same factory function.

Instead of the `staticmethod` variant, I'd usually use module-level functions.

Comment: By module-level function you mean one you can use on any model? That's what I hope to do eventually. Anyway, that fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: By module-level function I mean that i have a module `customer` (or whatever) with the class `Customer` and a function `customer_from_row()` which returns a new `Customer` instance.

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
@classmethod
def save_from_row(cls, row):
```

Class methods get the method's class as the first argument.